# How to link multiple select box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to do something like link multiple select box together, using jquery, is there a way to do it? For example, I got Select Box 1, 2, 3, each select box have options asa,b,c.  Now what i want is if select box 1 selected a,the other two select will not have selected option there,after i change select box 1 to null, the option should appear in other two also.

```html
<select id="1">
<option value="">Select an option</option>
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<select id="2">
<option value="">Select an option</option>
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
</select>


<select id="3">
<option value="">Select an option</option>
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: did you tried my demo @ly ?

Answer (score 0):

try to use these scripts, hope these will help dont forget to add your jquery library. Try these simple script.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script





 <script>

        $(function(){

        $(document).on("change","#1",function(){
          var el = $(this);
          var val = $.trim(el.val());
          (val == '') ?  $("#2,#3").val("").change() : $("#2,#3").val(val).change();
        });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: this is a simple script you want to add

Answer (score -1):

Check the below fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/ponmudi/h1qn3k4a/1/

```
$("select").change(function() {
    let curId = $(this).attr('id');
    let str = $(this).val();
    //"Select an option": "",
    var newOptions = {  
        "A": "A",
        "B": "B",
        "C": "C"
    };
    delete newOptions[str];
    $("select").each(function() {
        let nowId = $(this).attr('id');
        if (nowId !== curId) {
            $el = $("#" + nowId);
            $el.empty();
            $.each(newOptions, function(key, value) {
                $el.append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value", value).text(key));
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for you reply, i tried your method, but it will appear two same option in different box, for example i can have 2 select box with option A